# Are Dataframe parameters communitive?

Tags: pandas

I am wondering why `df[1:10]0[['col1','col2']]` and `df[['col1','col2']][1:10]` produces the same result. What Python data structure makes this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the answer is yes. The answer lies in the fact that both objects are of type `pd.DataFrame`. Note, however, that columns are indexed via `[[]]` rather than `[]` which resolves ambiguity of row/column index. Otherwise, you will get a `KeyError: ('col1', 'col2')`

Take, as a more simplistic example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3,4], 'b' : ['Hello', 'World', 'it\'s', 'me'], 'c' : [11,22,33,44]})
```

[image]

and compare both sub-frames via `pd.DataFrame.equals()` which yields

```
df[2:4][['a', 'c']].equals(other=df[['a', 'c']][2:4])
>True
```